# Как получить следующий элемент массива с помощью next php?

Tags: php

Не могу получить следующий элемент массива.

```
foreach ($manga as $item) {
    $glavs .= '<li><a href="?t='.$item["tom"].'&g='.$item["glava"].'&p=1">Том '.$item["tom"].' - Глава '.$item["glava"].'</a></li>';
    if(($item["glava"]) > $lastGlavaAll) $lastGlavaAll = $item["glava"];
    **if(($item["glava"]) == $glava) $lexGlava = $next["glava"];**   
}
 echo $lexGlava;
```

Если заменить $next на $item, то конструкция работает. Но мне нужен именно следующий элемент. Буду очень благодарен, если подскажете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл `foreach` можно писать не только

```
foreach ($manga as $item) {
```

но и

```
foreach ($manga as $key => $item) {
```

где `$key` - ключ массива.

Если ключ числовой, то тогда внутри цикла следующий элемент будет таков:

```
$next = $manga[$key + 1];
```

Comment: Гений! Работает)